# I am unable to find the xpath in IE11 Windows 10 with IEDriver

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to find the xpath for the following code. But it is showing some errors.
inspect element is:

```
<BUTTON title="Create Customer" class="SBCUSTMENU awbButton" id=C2_W10_V11_btnCREATE_CUSTMC onmouseout=javacript:awbImgButtonMouseOut(this); onmousedown=javacript:awbImgButtonMouseDown(this); onmouseup=javacript:awbImgButtonMouseUp(this); onclick="javascript:if(awbBtnActive(this)){if (awbAddMonitorIdsToHttp(['MONITOR_JOURNEY','','MONITOR_STEP',''])){htmlbSubmitLib('htmlb',this,'htmlb:button:click:null','myFormId','C2_W10_V11_btnCREATE_CUSTMC','onclick_CREATE_CUSTMC',0);}}return false;" type=button awbClass="awbButton SBCUSTMENU">&nbsp;</BUTTON>

driver.findElement(By.id("C2_W10_V11_btnCREATE_CUSTMC")).click();
```

I am expecting the below error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: C2_W10_V11_btnCREATE_CUSTMC
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'PC404441', ip: '10.27.101.9', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_192'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.enableFullPageScreenshot=true, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.forceShellWindowsApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:10768/, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
```

Comment: inspect path is <BUTTON title="Create Customer" class="SBCUSTMENU awbButton" id=C2_W10_V11_btnCREATE_CUSTMC onmouseout=javacript:awbImgButtonMouseOut(this); onmousedown=javacript:awbImgButtonMouseDown(this); onmouseup=javacript:awbImgButtonMouseUp(this); onclick="javascript:if(awbBtnActive(this)){if (awbAddMonitorIdsToHttp(['MONITOR_JOURNEY','','MONITOR_STEP',''])){htmlbSubmitLib('htmlb',this,'htmlb:button:click:null','myFormId','C2_W10_V11_btnCREATE_CUSTMC','onclick_CREATE_CUSTMC',0);}}return false;" type=button awbClass="awbButton SBCUSTMENU">&nbsp;</BUTTON>

Answer (score 0):

You might need to induce a WebDriverWait, if the element you are clicking is dynamically generated:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;

(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[title='Create Customer']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if the the element is present in FRAME or not - if it is present -> in that case you need to first switch to that frame and then perform the action.

```
driver.switchTo.frame(""); 
// perform the action
```

If not inside frame then you can use Explicit Waits:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, waitTime);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPath("")))

OR

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, waitTime);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
```

Comment: I tried the above method. But still facing the issue. My error is------>                     
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 5 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.cssSelector: button[title='Create Customer']
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'PC404441', ip: '10.27.101.9', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_192'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0....

Comment: Inside the frame i did like this   ----> WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[title='Create Customer']"))).click();

Comment: If you are able to switch to frame and still getting an exception. Then you might be having a nested frame. If yes then try these steps -> Start from the 1st frame -> driver.switchTo.frame(mainFrameindex); -> find the index of sub frame in the main frame -> driver.switchTo.frame(subIndex); -> then perform the action